# Enter key not working in Firefox - onkeypress (I know there are "answers" but...)

Tags: firefox, xpages, onkeypress

I've seen all the posts about this issue but I still can't get the enter key to work in Firefox.  Here are all my iterations of code and I've obviously changed it a hundred times to try and make it work.  I can get it to work in IE, not Firefox.  Alternate question: I'm new to xPages.  Where do I define a function in an xPage or do I have to make a script library and add it to resources?  Thanks all.

Mike

```
var metaChar = false;
var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (key == 13) {
    metaChar = true;
    event.returnValue = true;
    alert("true13");
}
if (key != 13) {
    if (metaChar) {
        alert("false");
        metaChar = false;
    } else {
        alert("true");
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}


　
　
/*
var vevent = event.keyCode || event.key // IE does not pass event to the function
if(vevent == window.event){
    code = event.keyCode;
}else{
    code = event.key;
} 

if(code == 13){ 
    event.returnValue = true; 
    alert("True"); 
} else { 
    event.returnValue = false; 
    return false;
    alert("False"); 
}
*/

var e = event.keyCode || event.which;
charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

if(charCode == 13){ 
    return true; 
    alert("True"); 
} else { 
    return false; 
    alert("False"); 
}
```

Comment: `eturn false`? unless that's a typo, the syntax error will kill the entire code block.

Comment: no, it's spelled correctly.  if also.  When I copied the code, the paste put in extra lines and I edited it and accidentally deleted the character(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your issue lies in trying to use `event` in your javascript. In XPages you need to use a different reference `thisEvent`, some info at [this link under "Getting event information"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_scripts_client.html). This is a quirk of the way XPages adds events on page load.

For your situation, I created a simple example XPage, which shows you how to capture the enter key in an eventHandler or using an inline function if you want to go that route. This works for me in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 11.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel id="panel1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var enterKey = function(eventParam) {
                var key = eventParam.keyCode || eventParam.which;
                console.log("key = " + key);
                if (key == 13) {
                    alert("script function - enter");
                    return true;
                }else{
                    alert("script function - other character");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <xp:inputText id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onkeypress" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                    var key = thisEvent.keyCode || thisEvent.which;
                    console.log("key = " + key);
                    if (key == 13) {
                        alert("button event script - enter");
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        alert("button event script - other character");
                        return false;
                    }
                    ]]>
                </xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:br />
        <xp:br />
        <xp:inputText id="button2">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onkeypress" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                    enterKey(thisEvent);
                    ]]>
                </xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Brian thank you for that information and your efforts.  I tried changing the event and I get a "false" alert when I don't press Enter using " thisEvent.returnValue = false; " but Enter doesn't get past this client side code when I use true instead of false.

Comment: In that case you'd have to switch the submit property on the eventHandlers to true, and return true in the CSJS when you want the SSJS to be carried out afterwards, return false in the CSJS otherwise.

Comment: I am already doing a full update and return true and false as in above code.  It works in IE, just not Firefox.

Comment: I've updated the example code with the mechanism I'm describing. I don't use the returnValue property. In the eventHandler, I just call `return true` or `return false` as appropriate.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that would be good returning from a function but I'm working directly in the field onkeypress client side code.  I tried both and they don't work.  I can give you the code offline but these fields don't allow me to put code in additional comments.

Comment: I tried it and now it works.  I've done that exact thing multiple times and it hasn't.  I don't know why but I'm not going to dig.  As long as it works.  Thank you for your help